# Publish.net core 3.0 as FDE for win on linux

Tags: continuous-integration, publish, .net-core-3.0

I need publish asp.net app as framework-dependent executable for windows.
Publishing runs in docker container (Gitlab CI) using official image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0.

Publish command is

```
dotnet publish -f netcoreapp3.0 -c Release -o result_folder -r win-x64 --self-contained false project.csproj
```

Publishing completed successfully but produces 90+ MB of files, some of them:

```
System.Private.CoreLib.dll
System.Private.Xml.dll
coreclr.dll
System.Linq.Expressions.dll
api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll
```

Result looks more like a self-contained executable, not framework-dependent I expect.

The same command run on windows produces 12+ MB of files. Result looks exacly like framework-dependent executable I expected.

The question is how I can take the same result on docker/linux?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was no problem in .net publish. Additional files were created by other CI activity.

So publish works fine on linux in docker!